# How to define an object type with dynamic keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a const object which looks like this:

```
export const Language: Values = {
  es: {urlValue: 'es', label: 'Spain'},
  en: {urlValue: 'en', label: 'Anything'},
  eb: {urlValue: 'eb', label: 'Other thing'},
};

export interface Values {
  [name: string]: Value;
}

export interface Value {
  urlValue;
  label;
  selected?;
}
```

Now somewhere in app, we read some data which has this format, which coincidentally has the exact same keys:

```
{
  es: 32,
  en: 11,
  eb: 56
}
```

So actually i need another object type like this:

```
export class AnotherObject {

  constructor(public es: number,
              public en: number,
              public eb: number) {
  }
}
```

But can i create this type also dynamically so that it automatically uses the keys of the Language object, or urlValue of "Value" type?

PS: The question is a simplified form of our exact use case, where we have multiple consts like Languages. So an automatism would be really helpful.

**Edit**: For the suggestion of @basarat - Since this object is a part of a parent object i actually need a type definiton in this part:

```
export class ParentObject {
  thatObjectAbove: AnotherObject;
  otherObjects: ..
  ..
}

export interface AnotherObject {
  [name: LanguageOptions]: number;
}
```

I have the error "An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead." on the 'name' part of line "[name: LanguageOptions]: number;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`keyof` type operator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45gSwNdWSjU) gives you the key names as a type:

```
export const Language = {
  es: {urlValue: 'es', label: 'Spain'},
  en: {urlValue: 'en', label: 'Anything'},
  eb: {urlValue: 'eb', label: 'Other thing'},
};

type LanguageOptions = keyof typeof Language; // 'es' | 'en' | 'eb'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have this error on the last line where you use keyof: 'Language' refers to a value, but is being used as type here.

Comment: Fixed. You need to get the type of the variable with `typeof` and then use `keyof` to get the keys of the type.

Comment: ok.. but still i can't use this 'type' as a key type... i edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067795/2224454):

I have achieved my goal with defining the AnotherObject as *type* rather than interface.

```
type LanguageOptions = keyof typeof Language;  // as from basarat's answer

type AnotherObject = {[key in LanguageOptions]: number}; // is actually a type, still is named as 'object' so that it is still compatible with the question's code
    
export class ParentObject {
  thatObjectAbove: AnotherObject;
  otherObjects: ..
  ..
}
```

As it is stated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24220), it is because of the strange behaviour of typescript, which can be fixed in this way.

So the end solution in one-liner:

```
thatObjectAbove: {[key in keyof typeof Language]: number};
```

or

```
thatObjectAbove: Record<keyof typeof Language, number>;  // Record is a built-in typescript type
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you might to change your code a bit?

```
class DynamicClass<T> {
    constructor(values?: { [key in keyof T]?: T[key] }) {
        for (const key of Object.keys(values)) {
            this[key] = values[key];
        }
    }
}

class MyClass extends DynamicClass<MyClass> {
    attr1: string;
    attB: number;
    obj: {
        wow: string,
        yeah: boolean
    };
}


new MyClass({
    attr1: 'a',
    obj: {
        wow: '',
        yeah: true
    },
    att
})
```

[image]